# Confusing installation of SDK on Catalina?

Tags: xcode

On Catalina, I see the following SDK directories. Since it is Catalina, why the first directory does not have MacOSX10.15.sdk.

What is the different use of the two SDKs directories?

```
$ ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 5 root wheel 160 2020/11/30-06:27:36 DriverKit20.2.sdk
drwxr-xr-x 7 root wheel 224 2021/01/03-08:10:34 MacOSX.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  10 2021/01/03-08:05:47 MacOSX11.1.sdk -> MacOSX.sdk
```

```
$ ls -l /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  14 2021/02/08-07:00:10 MacOSX.sdk -> MacOSX11.1.sdk
drwxr-xr-x 7 root wheel 224 2019/11/12-16:05:26 MacOSX10.14.sdk
drwxr-xr-x 8 root wheel 256 2021/02/08-07:00:56 MacOSX10.15.sdk
drwxr-xr-x 7 root wheel 224 2021/02/08-07:00:36 MacOSX11.1.sdk
```

Comment: How did you install Xcode and also the command line tools?

Comment: I don't remember the specifics. But I should have command line tools installed. What is the relation between the command line tools and xcode. Is there a way fix what has been installed if there is any error?

Comment: Why do you assume there is an error? Is something not working as expected?

Comment: There are some other tools unable to find the include directory. I don't know whose error it is. So I want to first understand where the include directory is supposed to be.